# RPI3 PIXEL Jessie - usb0 interface

Tags: android, networking, raspberry-pi

**Greetings to everyone!**

I have a project on RPI but I have 1 problem.

**Project description:** RPI (server, connected to LAN DHCP with internet access) + Android Tablet (connects on USB0 static interface on RPI via USB Tethering).

**Android App:** Made an android APP to connect to server and manage RPI as client via sockets and ajax requests.

**Problem:** I have made five examples of same thing with 5 tablets and 5 RPI-i and USB0 is being seen by LAN Router and the problem is that I want nobody from LAN (not even another tablet) can connect to USB0 but that tablet connected to RPI with USB Tethering. Now how 5 devices is connected to LAN sometimes happens that tablet from RPI1 connects via LAN to RPI2 beacuse USB0 can be seen on LAN.

I want that USB0 is not seen on LAN but can give internet to tablet via eth0.

Currently I'm giving USB0 internet like this:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE &&  sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o usb0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT && sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i usb0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

I would really be glad if somebody could help me I'm not so good in configuring network interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project. parts of it are probably quite useful for you.

https://github.com/samyk/poisontap/blob/master/pi_startup.sh